# R Shiny Playwith

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I was wondering if there is any possibility to embedded a playwith plot within a shiny panel ?
i.e., :

In server.R :

```
...
output$plot=renderPlot({playwith(plot(0~0)}) 
...
```

In ui.R :

```
...
plotOutput("plot")
...
```

If someone has a solution it would greatly help me !